# Hbase:Need suitable jar files for cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.2-0

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to load data from flat file to Hbase through API.But I am getting following error
         ========================================================
                                                                                      java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString
      (NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HServerAddress.(HServerAddress.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterAddressTracker.getMasterAddress(MasterAddressTracker.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
    at Hbase.readFromFile.main(readFromFile.java:16)

Code :

```
     package Hbase;

     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileReader;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.util.StringTokenizer;

     import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;


    public class readFromFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     if(args.length==1)
        {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create(new      Configuration());
        HBaseAdmin hba = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
        if(!hba.tableExists(args[0])){
            HTableDescriptor ht = new HTableDescriptor(args[0]);
            ht.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("sample"));
            ht.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("region"));
            ht.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("time"));
            ht.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("product"));
            ht.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("sale"));
            ht.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("profit"));
            hba.createTable(ht);
            System.out.println("New Table Created");

            HTable table = new HTable(conf,args[0]);

            File f = new File("/home/training/Desktop/data");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line = br.readLine();
            int i =1;
            String rowname="row";
            while(line!=null && line.length()!=0){
                System.out.println("Ok till here");
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
                rowname = "row"+i;
                Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowname));
                                                                                       p.add(Bytes.toBytes("sample"),Bytes.toBytes("sampleNo."),
       Bytes.toBytes(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
                p.add(Bytes.toBytes("region"),Bytes.toBytes("country"),
              Bytes.toBytes(tokens.nextToken()));
                p.add(Bytes.toBytes("region"),Bytes.toBytes("state"),
              Bytes.toBytes(tokens.nextToken()));
                p.add(Bytes.toBytes("region"),Bytes.toBytes("city"),
              Bytes.toBytes(tokens.nextToken()));
                p.add(Bytes.toBytes("time"),Bytes.toBytes("year"),
             Bytes.toBytes(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
                p.add(Bytes.toBytes("time"),Bytes.toBytes("month"),
              Bytes.toBytes(tokens.nextToken()));
                                                                                        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("product"),Bytes.toBytes("productNo."),
            Bytes.toBytes(tokens.nextToken()));
                p.add(Bytes.toBytes("sale"),Bytes.toBytes("quantity"),
            Bytes.toBytes(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
                p.add(Bytes.toBytes("profit"),Bytes.toBytes("earnings"),
              Bytes.toBytes(tokens.nextToken()));
                i++;
                table.put(p);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
                br.close();
                table.close();
            }
        else
            System.out.println("Table Already exists.
           Please enter another table name");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Please Enter the table 
         name through command line");       
    }
    }
```

Please let me know whether we need to add any suitable jars ..I am using cloudera cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.2-0

Thanks,
VJ

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error, it says that the `Integer.parseInt` method raised a `NumberFormatException`. This means that you attempted to convert a String of invalid format into an Integer. In your code, you call that method in this line:

`Bytes.toBytes(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));`

You need look at the tokens you're passing into this method via `tokens.nextToken()` and ensure that each can be converted to an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the cloudera jar versions used. Please check on it, that should work.